# What is the proper way to change http headers in a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, http-headers

I'm building a chrome extension and would like to place a onedrive document in an iframe. It seems that no matter how I alter the following code, I can't seem to get the cross origin error to go away.

Url:

```
https://1drv.ms/x/s!ArcbZ_8xcTVdjBBU8wRdvhJgvPcw
```

Manifest permissions:

```
"webRequest",
"webRequestBlocking",
```

Event Listener:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function (details) {
        for (var i = 0; i < details.responseHeaders.length; i++) {
            if (details.responseHeaders[i].name.toLowerCase() === 'x-frame-options') {
                details.responseHeaders.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
        return { requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders };
    },
    { urls: ['https://onedrive.live.com/*'] },
    ['blocking', 'responseHeaders']
);
```

I've tried removing the x-frame-options with and without "blocking". I'm sure this is just a minor syntax issue.

Comment: You splice responseHeaders but return requestHeaders. See [Getting around X-Frame-Options DENY in a Chrome extension?](//stackoverflow.com/a/15534822)

Comment: Different question, same answer.